# jquery.kyco.googleplusfeed.min.js Unminified Source code

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-plus, unminify

Where is the unminified jquery.kyco.googleplusfeed.min.js source code?

All source files are minified at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/kyco/jquery.kyco.googleplusfeed).

Comment: isn't [this](https://github.com/kyco/jquery.kyco.googleplusfeed/blob/master/src/jquery.kyco.googleplusfeed.js) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the unminified source code for jquery.kyco.googleplusfeed.js:

https://github.com/kyco/jquery.kyco.googleplusfeed/blob/master/src/jquery.kyco.googleplusfeed.js

Answer (score -1):

The unminified source can be found [here](https://github.com/kyco/jquery.kyco.googleplusfeed/blob/master/src/jquery.kyco.googleplusfeed.js). You might also want to take a look at the source code of v2 [here](https://github.com/kyco/jquery.kyco.googleplusfeed2/blob/master/dist/jquery.kyco.googleplusfeed2.js).

Comment: corhero: in v2 version they have used [link](http://www.kycosoftware.com/api/googleplus-feed/) which is not in first version, using this link they made some changes in feeds result and use there api key at backend.